# on rational normal curves and determinantal representation

Tags: algebraic-geometry

**Background:** Let 
\begin{align}
\Omega = \begin{bmatrix} L_1 & L_2 & \cdots & L_n \\  M_1 & M_2 & \cdots & M_n \end{bmatrix}\end{align} be a matrix of linear forms on $\mathbb{P}^n$ such that for every $[\lambda : \mu] \in \mathbb{P}^1$, the linear forms $\lambda L_1 + \mu M_1,\dots, \lambda L_n + \mu M_n$ are linearly independent. The determinantal locus of $\Omega$, i.e. the variety given by $L_i M_j - L_j M_i =0$ is a rational normal curve (recall that the canonical rational normal curve is the image of the veronese map $v_n : \mathbb{P}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$). The determinantal variety of $\Omega$ can also be thought of as the image of the map $\mathbb{P}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$, that takes $[\lambda : \mu] \in \mathbb{P}^1$ to the point $p_{[\lambda,\mu]}$ of intersection of the $n$ hyperplanes of $\mathbb{P}^n$ given by 
\begin{align}
\lambda L_1 + \mu M_1=\dots= \lambda L_n + \mu M_n=0.
\end{align} Observe that the two descriptions agree since every equation $\lambda L_i + \mu M_i = \lambda L_j + \mu M_j=0$ is equivalent to the equation $L_i M_j - L_j M_i =0$. As a final remark, note that each linear form on $\mathbb{P}^n$ can be thought of as a polynomial of degree $n$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$. This is because $\mathbb{P}^n$ can be realized as the projectivization of the $n^{th}$ symmetric power of the two-dimensional vector space associated to $\mathbb{P}^1$.

**Question:** Notice that by definition, the point $p_{[1,0]}$ is a root of every $L_j$. Then Harris, in Algebraic-Geometry: A First Course, p. 102, makes a statement that i can not understand. He says:

> The remaining $n-1$ zeros of $L_j$, corresponding to $\mu \neq 0$, must be zeros of $M_j$.

Why is that the case? If $\lambda L_j + \mu M_j=0 \, \, (*)$ was an identity, then i could certainly see the truth of the statement. What confuses me is that $(*)$ is not an identity, rather we are interested in points that satisfy this relation. It seems that $(*)$ can be interpreted as an identity in some sense (supporting Harris's statement), however it is unclear to me in what sense.

For completeness, here is the precise excerpt from Harris:
[image: The precise excerpt from Harris]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $[\lambda:\mu]\in\mathbb{P}^{1}-[1:0]$ such that $p_{[\lambda:\mu]}$ is a zero of $L_{j}$. Since  $p_{[\lambda:\mu]}$ is contained in the intersection of the hypersurfaces
$$
\lambda L_{1}+\mu M_{1}=\cdots=\lambda L_{n}+\mu M_{n}=0,
$$ 
we have that
$$
\lambda L_{j}(p_{[\lambda:\mu]})+\mu M_{j}(p_{[\lambda:\mu]})=0.
$$
Now, taking into account that $p_{[\lambda:\mu]}$ is a zero of $L_{j}$, we conclude that
$$
\mu M_{j}(p_{[\lambda:\mu]})=0,
$$
and therefore $M_{j}(p_{[\lambda:\mu]})=0$, because $\mu\neq 0$.

Comment: Yes, that's it.